# creating base model class in yii

Tags: yii

In my application, i have fields that are common to all tables, like create date, update date etc. To assign these values i'm using `beforeValidate` callback. Now, this `callback` is same for all models.

To avoid code duplication, i want to create a base model class.

But, when I tried to create a base model, yii thrown error saying `table cannot be found in database`, which is true since I dont have any table for this base model.

Is there any way I can create a base model class.

Comment: @bool.dev i'm using activerecord

Comment: ok..see my edited solution..it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [CTimeStampBehavior](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CTimestampBehavior).

Incase that doesn't help you, you can just write a *behavior* class yourself.

Hope this helps.

**Edit:**
Assuming you are using ActiveRecords.

If you want to create a new base model, you can do this:

```
abstract class MyBaseARClass extends CActiveRecord{
    protected function beforeValidate(){
            if(parent::beforeValidate()){
                    // assign your fields
                    return true;
            }
            else return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: imho, you should go for ctimestampbehavior if it can be used in your case, otherwise ofcourse you can use a new base class, lemme know if any clarifications are required.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you work with dynamic DB structure or have other reasons to work with Yii ActiveRecord without creating classes for each table in DB, you may use [smartActiveRecord yii extension](https://github.com/Nayjest/YiiSmartActiveRecord)

I separated it few minuts ago from my other extension -- AR behavior that adds versioning to any model (it copies all data on insert & update to special table (and create it if it's absent), that have a same structure as source table + "revision field" and primary key extended by this field.

Look at [SmartAR.php source](https://github.com/Nayjest/YiiSmartActiveRecord/blob/master/protected/extensions/components/smartActiveRecord/SmartAR.php), there is example of usage in comments.

Comment: Also you can create base class & specific classes for each table, then you need to define at least "tableName" & static "model" methods in each specific model class. (Or you can try to detect table name in base class using get_class($this)

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a base table? Thinking about the Yii framework it may be easier to have a relationship between a model and the base model.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you need to override

```
public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}
```

in every child class so Yii would know which table to use for your model. Otherwise it will try and use base class as table name.

I.e.

```
class User extends BaseActiveRecord {

    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

}
```